# Windows 10 Power Issues (Sleep and Shutdown)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, shutdown

I have Windows 10 Home x64 running on Dell Inspiron 3537. All the drivers are ok (sidetrack; gave it on a warranty service, hdd failure; they put a new drive in and reinstalled it with win10 home) and for the first few days, it worked great. Then came the problem. Whenever I close the lid or put the PC to sleep, it will sometimes go to sleep, but sometimes everything will shut down (hdd, wifi led etc.), but the fan will stay on and the pc will stay in on state instead of sleep (power led blinking) state. Same is for shutting down: sometimes it will shutdown ok (it takes up to 10-15 secs) but sometimes it will stay on indefinitely. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: the windows installation is brand new and as i said, it sometimes shuts down / sleeps and sometimes it doesn't; i can't see what is the problem

Comment: @DavidPostill i think it's not related to this

Comment: *(shrug)*, you can't know that until you look at the logs.

Comment: The last Shutdown Performance Monitoring logs are from last week

Comment: Did you try disabling fast boot from power options ?

Comment: @Elie if it continues not to work, i'll try that

Comment: @Elie disabling fastboot did not work, the thing is when i use the pc for a short period of time (an hour tops) everything is ok, but when i use it for a few hours (3-4) sometimes (like now) it doesn't shutdown properly